# how can i add category meta under the post date?

Tags: wordpress, categories, meta

my link is madbabe.co

inside the grid only has title and date , I want category under the date.

i have found the code for the date, don't know how to add more code to display category.

```
    // Display date if $date is true
                            if ( 'true' == $date ) {

                                $date_output = '';

                                if ( $first_run ) {
                                    $date_style = vcex_inline_style( array(
                                        'color'     => $date_color,
                                        'font_size' => $date_font_size,
                                    ) );
                                }

                                $date_output .= '<div class="vcex-blog-entry-date entry-date"' . $date_style . '>';

                                    $date_output .= get_the_date();

                                $date_output .= '</div>';

                                $output .= apply_filters( 'vcex_blog_grid_date', $date_output, $latts );

                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making that whole code this:

```
// Display date if $date is true
                        if ( 'true' == $date ) {

                            $date_output = '';
                            $id = get_the_ID();
                            $cats = wp_get_post_categories($id);

                            if ( $first_run ) {
                                $date_style = vcex_inline_style( array(
                                    'color'     => $date_color,
                                    'font_size' => $date_font_size,
                                ) );
                            }

                            $date_output .= '<div class="vcex-blog-entry-date entry-date"' . $date_style . '>';

                            $date_output .= get_the_date();

                            $date_output .= '</div>';

                            $date_output .= '<br><div>' . $cats[0]->name; . '</div>';

                            $output .= apply_filters( 'vcex_blog_grid_date', $date_output, $latts );

                        }
```

Comment: hi it shows syntax error, unexpected '.' :" date_output .= '<br><div>' . $cats[0]->name; . '</div>';"

Comment: Oh sorry, remove the `;` after `$cats[0]->name` and try it.

Comment: i have replaced it but it still not showing category meta but blank space.

Comment: did it display anything?  can you give me some more info on what happened?

Comment: it didnt display anything, please go to my website have a look please

Comment: I would like to try to troubleshoot.  please replace `$cats[0]->name` with `"test"` INCLUDING the quotes.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but did you actually assign those posts to a category?

Comment: yes because inside the post page it does show the category

Comment: Ok, try this then for that specific line: `$date_output .= '<br><div>  <?php echo $cats[0]->name; ?></div>';`